# Android TextView textColor doesn't change (AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello fellow stackflowers, I am need if your help.

I am using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.NoActionBar` theme in my mobile application.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
```

The `android:textColor` property seems to be ignored in my fragment. The text color defaults to a `grey` color. It works fine in the preview window.

I have also tried using a theme for the textview Element without any luck.

Here is the style theme I use.

```
<style name="textView">           
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorIcons</item>          
        </style>

  <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Client Name"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/textView"
            />
```

What's more surprising is that when I set `android:background"` the background shows as expected. But it's the text color I want to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the theme is applied to your application in AndroidManifest.xml

If that alone doesn't work try inserting this in your fragment's onCreateView() .

```
final Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity,R.style.textView)
final LayoutInflater inflater1 = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
```

Use this inflater1 to inflate the fragment's view.

Comment: Hello Harsha, I did that and now the Text color of the button only changed. The TextView still remains gray. Isn't this weird? what's so special about TextView.

Comment: John .Do not overide theme inside text view.Just remove theme inside textview.

Comment: Hi Harsha i've solved my problem. It appears that I was using  android:hint="Client Name" the default color for hint is gray. Changing hint to text worked :) silly mistake thanks for your help.